# Shellexecute in vb6 is not working in windows7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, shellexecute

Shellexecute() is not working in windows7

When i tried to open some URL from the code, it throws an errror.

It returns a value 5.

Please some one look into this issue and help me to resolve

Comment: Could you also give an example of the URL you are trying to open?

Comment: @gat: "http://cms.rd.xxx.com" internal website. Am also trying to open within the network only.

Comment: Could you also post the part of your code that you are using to call `ShellExecute()`?

Answer (score 1):

SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED = 5

> The operating system denied access to the specified file.

The cause of problem might be lots of things.  Perhaps the default browser was not installed properly but ended up putting registry keys in virtualized locations?  Maybe the URL needs authentication?

[Chrome not registered correctly anymore. Can't be launched from admin apps.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156400)